# Python Hashtable returning reference to object instead of data

Tags: python, object, hashtable

I am attempting to load a hash table from csv that can them be searched via a key value. It appears the insert function is working properly; however, when searching by key it returns "None". I added print lines into the code to confirm the object items are being loaded to the hash table. It appears object references are being inserted. When looping through the hash table, the print function for each bucket does not seem to match that. Does any one have any ideas why this is happening?
(I have separated the pages in code as "#MAIN---,#PACKAGE----,#HASH----)

```
# MAIN----------
import hash
import package


# Create instance of chaining hash table
newHash = hash.chainHashTable(40)
print(newHash.table)

# Load package data to hash table
newHash = package.loadPackageData('WGUPS Package File.csv', newHash)
print(newHash.table)
for i in range(len(newHash.table) + 1):
    print('Package: {}'.format(newHash.searchHash(i + 1)))


#HASH-----------
class chainHashTable:
    # Assign empty list to buckets
    def __init__(self, initial_capacity = 10):
        # establish table with empty list entries
        self.table = []
        for i in range(initial_capacity):
            self.table.append([])

    # Inserts a new item into the hash table and updates.
    def insertHash(self, key, item):
        # determine bucket for insert
        bucket = hash(key) % len(self.table)
        bucket_list = self.table[bucket]
        # update key if it is already in the bucket
        for kv in bucket_list:
            if kv[0] == key:
                kv[1] = item
                return True
        # if not in bucket, insert item
        key_value = [key, item]
        bucket_list.append(key_value)
        return True

    # Search for an item with matching key
    def searchHash(self, key):
        # determine proper bucket
        bucket = hash(key) % len(self.table)
        bucket_list = self.table[bucket]
        # loop for the key in the bucket list
        for kv in bucket_list:
            if kv[0] == key:
                return kv[1]
            else:
                return None

#PACKAGE-----
import csv
import hash


# Create package class / time complexity of O(1)
class Package:
    def __init__(self, pID, address, city, state, zip, dd, weight, notes, loc):
        self.package_id = pID
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zip = zip
        self.delivery_time = dd
        self.weight = weight
        self.notes = notes
        self.location = loc

    # Overwrite print(Package) to avoid outputting object reference
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (self.package_id, self.address, self.city, self.state, self.zip,
                                                       self.delivery_time, self.weight, self.notes, self.location)


# Create function to read package data csv file and set to object
def loadPackageData(file, hashTable):
    with open(file) as package_file:
        pd = csv.reader(package_file, delimiter=',')
        next(pd)
        for pack in pd:
            # change time format to 24hrs for standardization
            if pack[5] == '9:00 AM':
                pack[5] = '0900'
            elif pack[5] == '10:30 AM':
                pack[5] = '1030'
            elif pack[5] == 'EOD':
                pack[5] = '1700'

            pID = pack[0]
            address = pack[1]
            city = pack[2]
            state = pack[3]
            zip = pack[4]
            delivery_time = pack[5]
            weight = pack[6]
            notes = pack[7]
            location = 'At Hub'

            # Create package object
            p = Package(pID, address, city, state, zip, delivery_time, weight, notes, location)
            # Insert package into table
            hashTable.insertHash(pID, p)
    return hashTable
```

The above code outputs:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]

[[['', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D160>]], [], [['26', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AD90>]], [['3', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D3A0>]], [], [['28', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379ADF0>], ['39', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AC40>]], [['WGUPS Package File', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D190>]], [['37', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AFA0>]], [['Package\nID', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D1C0>], ['30', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AE50>]], [['40', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AC10>]], [['2', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D400>]], [['19', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D460>], ['31', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AD30>]], [['8', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D670>], ['16', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D520>], ['23', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379ACA0>], ['35', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AF40>]], [['32', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AEB0>]], [['NHP1 : WGUPS Routing Program', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D1F0>]], [['36', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AF70>]], [['4', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D430>], ['6', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D6D0>]], [['11', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D5E0>], ['33', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AE80>]], [], [['5', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379DBB0>], ['21', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379A040>]], [['13', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D580>], ['18', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D4F0>], ['24', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AD00>]], [], [['12', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D5B0>]], [['20', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D490>]], [['7', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D6A0>]], [['1', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D0A0>]], [['34', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AEE0>]], [['25', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AD60>], ['27', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379ADC0>]], [['10', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D610>], ['15', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D9D0>]], [], [['29', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AE20>]], [], [], [['14', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D550>], ['22', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379ACD0>]], [['17', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D4C0>]], [['9', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379D640>]], [], [], [], [['38', <package.Package object at 0x000002A05379AFD0>]]]

Package: None
Package: None
Package: None
etc.
```

For example the desired output would be:
Package:3060 Lester St,West Valley City,UT,84119,10:30 AM,88,Delayed on flight---will not arrive to depot until 9:05 am

Comment: You are calling `.insertHash()` with string keys, but calling `.searchHash()` with integer keys - of course nothing is found.  (And to get your `Package` objects to print properly inside a list, you need to define a `.__repr__()` method, not just `.__str__()`.  Putting `__repr__ = __str__` at the end of the class definition would be one way to fix that.)

Comment: (Though from a design standpoint; I would define `__repr__` instead of `__str__`. `__repr__` is automatically used if `__str__` isn't available.) Plus, the conventional expectations of what `__repr__` should produce means that a definition of `__repr__` is always suitable for use as `__str__`, but the reverse is not always true.

Comment: This helped a lot thank you. No idea how I missed casting the string to integer. Implemented both changes and it works as expected

Answer (score 1):

When inserting the object you are inserting them by reference:

```
# Create package object
p = Package(pID, address, city, state, zip, delivery_time, weight, notes, location)
# Insert package into table
hashTable.insertHash(pID, p)
```

Instead of an object, as it does not have any methods whatsoever, I would reccomend to you to use a dictionary, as so:

```
for pack in pd:
            # change time format to 24hrs for standardization
            if pack[5] == '9:00 AM':
                pack[5] = '0900'
            elif pack[5] == '10:30 AM':
                pack[5] = '1030'
            elif pack[5] == 'EOD':
                pack[5] = '1700'

            dict = {
                     "pID" : pack[0]
                     "address" : pack[1]
                     "city" : pack[2]
                     "state" : pack[3]
                     "zip" : pack[4]
                     "delivery_time" : pack[5]
                     "weight" : pack[6]
                     "notes" : pack[7]
                     "location" : 'At Hub'
            }
```

You can handle the dict natively, if You need to implement methods, I reccomend usign dict for handling the data and, on the constructor of the class, accepting a dict and building the object when the methods are necessary.